# Unsemantic table markup generated using Marionette ItemView when tr has to live in template

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

I have a problem with the markup being output for each `Marionette.ItemView`, I need to place a `tr` inside my template instead of assigning it as the `ItemView` tagName but by doing this each of my `tr` tags are wrapped in a `div` as standard, this breaks the layout and messes up semantics. Can anyone suggest how I can resolve this? I need the `tr` in my template as I need to output multiple tr tags by array length.

**JS**

```
var PersonView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    template: '.js-person-tmpl',

    templateHelpers: function () {
        return {
            availableClasses: this.options.availableClasses.toJSON()
        }
    },

    initialize: function () {
        console.log('PersonView::initialize', this.options);
    }
});

// CompositeView Class
var PersonsView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

    template: '.js-persons-tmpl',
    childView: PersonView,
    childViewContainer: '.js-tbody',

    childViewOptions: function () {
        return {
            availableClasses: this.options.available
        }
    },

    initialize: function () {
        console.log('PersonsView::initialize', this.options);
    },

    onRender: function () {
        console.log('PersonsView::onRender');
    }
});
```

**Template**

```
<script type="text/html" class="js-person-tmpl">
    <% _.each(bookedClasses, function(booked, i) { %>
    <tr> 
        <% if(i == 0) { %>
            <td rowspan="2"><%= name %></td>
        <% } %>
        <td>
            <%= booked %>
            <button class="action action--remove js-action--remove"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><g><path d="M12,2C6.5,2,2,6.5,2,12c0,5.5,4.5,10,10,10s10-4.5,10-10C22,6.5,17.5,2,12,2z M16.9,15.5l-1.4,1.4L12,13.4l-3.5,3.5   l-1.4-1.4l3.5-3.5L7.1,8.5l1.4-1.4l3.5,3.5l3.5-3.5l1.4,1.4L13.4,12L16.9,15.5z"/></g></svg></button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option>Please select...</option>
                <% _.each(availableClasses, function(available) { %>
                    <option value="<%= available.id %>"><%= available.name %></option>
                <% }) %>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% }) %> 
</script>
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/tx62jrvg/19/

Each ItemView render currently outputs:

```
<div>
    <tr> 
        <td>Kenneth Wise</td>
        <td>
            375
            <button class="action action--remove js-action--remove"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><g><path d="M12,2C6.5,2,2,6.5,2,12c0,5.5,4.5,10,10,10s10-4.5,10-10C22,6.5,17.5,2,12,2z M16.9,15.5l-1.4,1.4L12,13.4l-3.5,3.5   l-1.4-1.4l3.5-3.5L7.1,8.5l1.4-1.4l3.5,3.5l3.5-3.5l1.4,1.4L13.4,12L16.9,15.5z"></path></g></svg></button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option>Please select...</option>

                    <option value="34">Core Evo</option>

                    <option value="686">Core Body Workout</option>

                    <option value="870">Boxercise</option>

                    <option value="1345">Rapid Circuits</option>

            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr> 
        <td>Kenneth Wise</td>
        <td>
            980
            <button class="action action--remove js-action--remove"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><g><path d="M12,2C6.5,2,2,6.5,2,12c0,5.5,4.5,10,10,10s10-4.5,10-10C22,6.5,17.5,2,12,2z M16.9,15.5l-1.4,1.4L12,13.4l-3.5,3.5   l-1.4-1.4l3.5-3.5L7.1,8.5l1.4-1.4l3.5,3.5l3.5-3.5l1.4,1.4L13.4,12L16.9,15.5z"></path></g></svg></button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option>Please select...</option>

                    <option value="34">Core Evo</option>

                    <option value="686">Core Body Workout</option>

                    <option value="870">Boxercise</option>

                    <option value="1345">Rapid Circuits</option>

            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the bookedClasses property on the Person model refer to an available time slot or something?

Comment: Hey, bookedClasses just refers to a slots the user has booked, just name of the class and it's id. So the user can have multiple classes that's why their name appears multiple times

Comment: So, the ids in bookedClasses refer to availableClasses?

Comment: Yeah that's correct, that availableClasses data is supposed to represent the classes left at that moment. A user can then swap out their current bookings for the ones in that list or delete any of their booked classes

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to not store the booked classes on the `Person` model, but introduce a `Booking` model that stores a class and a person.

```
var Booking = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        person: null,
        klass: null
    }
});

var Bookings = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Booking
});
```

Every time a person books a class, you create a new `Booking` model. You render the `Bookings` collection with your `PersonsView` where you `PersonView` represents exactly one `tr`. That way you can set `PersonView::tagName` to `'tr'`.

The dummy data for bookings would be:

```
var bookings = [{
    person: 1,
    klass: 375
}, {
    person: 1,
    klass: 980
}, {
    person: 2,
    klass: 234
}, {
    person: 2,
    klass: 768
}];
```

Comment: The data I have in as dummy is a minor representation of data I'm getting back from the server and don't have a lot of control over

Comment: Ok, this solution is probably to much work then. I have another question related to your last comment on the opening post. You are rendering all bookings for all users. Can users see each others bookings?

Comment: This is kind of a bad example to be honest, it's just all fake at the moment but this would all actually be managed by one person instead of multiple users

Comment: Well, the other solution is see would be ditching tables and building a table-like structure with the bootstrap grid system or something similar.

Comment: Can I ask a question regarding the bookedClasses array in my data, is it possible to make this a collection by accessing the bookedClasses property in the personsData or Persons Collection?

Comment: Yes, you could just process the personsData array to an array of objects with the values you want in the new collection. What should the models in this collection look like?